# Does precedence matter in ocaml parser?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, ocamlyacc

For example if I was writing a parser.mly file like, and I have this written for expressions

```
expr:
    expr PLUS   expr { Binop($1, Add,   $3)   }
  | expr DIVIDE expr { Binop($1, Divide,   $3)   }
```

Would this be the same as

```
expr:
    expr DIVIDE   expr { Binop($1, Divide,   $3)   }
  | expr PLUS expr { Binop($1, Add,   $3)   }
```

Like I guess I'm asking if the order in which things are listed vertically matter in determining parsing precedence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ocamlyacc and menhir require that you explicitly declare precedence, using the `%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc` declarations. The order of productions is not relevant.